# -emit-llvm can not be used while linking

Tags: makefile, linker, llvm, clang++, llvm-ir

I am trying to get LLVM bitcode `Example.bc` using `-emit-llvm -S` option.
but I am building my file using a static library

`CXXFLAGS += -emit-llvm -S`

`@Clang++ $(CFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) Example.cpp -L$(LIB_PATH) -lpthread`

I get the error -emit-llvm can not be used while linking  . How can I get I get LLVM IR while linking to static library ?

Comment: Emitting IR happens early during the compilation process. Linking happens much later, after the IR has been read, processed, converted to MIR and then to target native code.

Comment: Checkout https://github.com/travitch/whole-program-llvm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compiler with `-flto` flag will generate object files in LLVM bitcode format.
`-save-temps` given to clang at link time will save temporary files(completely linked) in bitcode format. It can be converted to LLVM IR with `llvm-dis`